# Computing Cost function for Linear regression with one variable without using Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm new with Matlab and Machine Learning and I tried to compute a cost function for a gradient descent.

The function computeCost takes 3 arguments:

- **X**  mx2 Matrix
- **y** m-dimensional vector
- **theta** : 2-dimensional vector

I already have a solution using matrix multiplication

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
  m = length(Y);
  h = X * theta;
  sError = (h - y) .^ 2;
  J = sum(sError) / (2 * m);
end
```

But now, I tried to do the same without matrix multiplication

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
  m = length(Y);
  S = 0;
  for i = 1:m
    h = X(i, 1) + theta(2) * X(i, 2);
    S = S + ((h - y(i)) ^ 2);
  end
  J = (1/2*m) * S;
end
```

But I didn't get the same result, and first is good for sure (I already use it before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two slight (but fundamental) errors - they are pretty simple errors though that certainly can be overlooked.

---

1. You forgot to include the bias term in your hypothesis:

   ```
   h = X(i,1)*theta(1) + X(i,2)*theta(2);
   %//         ^^^^^^
   ```

   Remember, the hypothesis when it comes to linear regression is equal to `theta^{T}*x`.  You didn't include all of the `theta` terms - only the second term.
2. Your last statement to normalize by `(2*m)` is slightly off.  You currently have it as:

   ```
   J = (1/2*m) * S;
   ```

   Because multiplication and division have the same rules of operation, this is the same as `(1/2)*m` and that's not what you want.  Just make sure that the `(2*m)` has brackets surrounding itself to ensure that this is evaluated as `S / (2*m)`:

   ```
   J = (1/(2*m)) * S;
   ```

   This will ensure that `2*m` is evaluated first, then the reciprocal of that is taken with the multiplication of the sum of squared errors.

---

When you fix those problems, you will get the same results as using the matrix formulation.

BTW, slight typo in your code.  It should be `m = length(y)`, not `m = length(Y)`.

Comment: I got the first one, but i thinking i was wrong. But the second... Thanks !

Comment: @Arthur - My pleasure :) The second I overlooked initially, but then I figured it out.  Good luck!